# What is the difference between transition function (delta) and extended transition function (delta hat) in finite automata?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

What is the difference between transition function delta ($\delta$) and extended transition function delta hat ($\hat{\delta}$) in finite automata?

Both of them, when started at a state $q$ for a string $w$, will lead to the same state $p$. So what is the difference?

See, for example, page 15 of the third edition of Dexter Kozen's *Automata and Computability* (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-85706-5)

Comment: Please define the "extended transition function" -- it's not a concept I'm familiar with. And, I suggest that, if you write out the definition, the difference from the standard transition function should become obvious.

Comment: Please edit the question to add a reference to the textbook or article you are talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read some references in order to answer your question.

- **Transition function:** takes as arguments a state and an input symbol and returns a state, denoted by $\delta$.
- ***Extended* transition function:** Describes what happens when we start in any state and follow any sequence of inputs. It is a function that takes a state $q$ and a string $w$ and returns a state $p$ (the state that the automaton reaches when starting in state $q$ and processing the sequence of inputs $w$). It is denoted by $\hat{\delta}$.

**In simple terms:** transition function takes two parameters: a state and a *symbol*, while extended transition function takes a state and a *string*.

### Example of transition function

[image: Example 1]

### Example of *extended* transition function

[image: Example 2]